# How to load different content(content which is different from already loaded content) on button click in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am displaying results from json in a react bootstrap table. On clicking compare, the results get filtered within the table. Now I wanted to reload and display the selected products in a different tabular format on clicking "Compare". The page should reload and then only the selected products should display in a table with headers vertically aligned. Can any one please help? Full code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/o4nw18wy8q

Expected output sample on clicking compare -

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to have a function inside your class to return two different views based the state of your `filter status`. If the filter status is not true, then display the normal view, if `filter status` is `true`, then display the `view` that you have just mentioned in the above view. As far as the design is concerned, you should be able to work out the table designs.

And when you hit `clear`, then you should set the filter status back to `false`

This is not a full working code. I am just giving you some idea.

Here is a codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/2x450x3rqn

Answer (score 0):

You can return a view from the function

```
onButtonClick = () => {
...
...
return <BootstrapTable
          keyField="PartNumber"
          selectRow={updatedData}
          data={updatedData}
          columns={updatedData}
        />
}
```